# What does "LS4" or "LS16" mean when searching for Adobe software like Fireworks or CS Master Collection?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-fireworks

I often find the name of the Adobe software and "LS4" or "LS16" next to it. What does it mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the Language Selection that the package has.

LS4 contains:

- Deutsch - German
- Español - Spanish
- Español América Latina - Spanish
- Français Canadien - French
- Français - French
- Italiano - Italian
- Nederlands - Dutch
- Português do Brasil - Brazilian Portuguese
- Svenska - Swedish

LS16 has:

- English
- Japanese (not sure)